# Using Sympy to integrate a complicated expression. Program does not terminate even after an hour

Tags: python, sympy, symbolic-integration

I am trying to compute a definite integral using `sympy`. Below is my code:

```
import sympy as sp
import math

eps, psi = sp.symbols("eps psi", positive=True)
y = 1 / (math.sqrt(8)*math.pi**2)*sp.integrate(1/sp.sqrt(eps - psi) * d2crho_dpsi2, (psi, 0, eps))
```

I have pre-computed `d2crho_dpsi2` and it is a complicated expression in terms of `psi`. It is as follows:

```
(110826921669719*(-110826921669719*psi**2/(500000000000000*(1 + (-psi - 134335984549343*LambertW(-74440218185373*psi*exp(-74440218185373*psi/500000000000000)/500000000000000)/20000000000000)/psi)**2*(-74440218185373*psi/500000000000000 - LambertW(-74440218185373*psi*exp(-74440218185373*psi/500000000000000)/500000000000000))**2) - 20*psi/((1 + (-psi - 134335984549343*LambertW(-74440218185373*psi*exp(-74440218185373*psi/500000000000000)/500000000000000)/20000000000000)/psi)**3*(-psi - 134335984549343*LambertW(-74440218185373*psi*exp(-74440218185373*psi/500000000000000)/500000000000000)/20000000000000)))*(-110826921669719*psi**3*log(1 + (-psi - 134335984549343*LambertW(-74440218185373*psi*exp(-74440218185373*psi/500000000000000)/500000000000000)/20000000000000)/psi)/(25000000000000*(-74440218185373*psi/500000000000000 - LambertW(-74440218185373*psi*exp(-74440218185373*psi/500000000000000)/500000000000000))**3) + 74440218185373*psi**2/(2500000000000*(1 + (-psi - 134335984549343*LambertW(-74440218185373*psi*exp(-74440218185373*psi/500000000000000)/500000000000000)/20000000000000)/psi)*(-74440218185373*psi/500000000000000 - LambertW(-74440218185373*psi*exp(-74440218185373*psi/500000000000000)/500000000000000))**2) + 134335984549343*psi/(200000000000*(1 + (-psi - 134335984549343*LambertW(-74440218185373*psi*exp(-74440218185373*psi/500000000000000)/500000000000000)/20000000000000)/psi)**2*(-psi - 134335984549343*LambertW(-74440218185373*psi*exp(-74440218185373*psi/500000000000000)/500000000000000)/20000000000000)))/(500000000000000000*(-110826921669719*psi**2*log(1 + (-psi - 134335984549343*LambertW(-74440218185373*psi*exp(-74440218185373*psi/500000000000000)/500000000000000)/20000000000000)/psi)/(5000000000000000*(-74440218185373*psi/500000000000000 - LambertW(-74440218185373*psi*exp(-74440218185373*psi/500000000000000)/500000000000000))**2) + psi/((1 + (-psi - 134335984549343*LambertW(-74440218185373*psi*exp(-74440218185373*psi/500000000000000)/500000000000000)/20000000000000)/psi)*(-psi - 134335984549343*LambertW(-74440218185373*psi*exp(-74440218185373*psi/500000000000000)/500000000000000)/20000000000000)))**2) + (65999841839257*psi**3/(100000000000000*(1 + (-psi - 134335984549343*LambertW(-74440218185373*psi*exp(-74440218185373*psi/500000000000000)/500000000000000)/20000000000000)/psi)**2*(-74440218185373*psi/500000000000000 - LambertW(-74440218185373*psi*exp(-74440218185373*psi/500000000000000)/500000000000000))**3) + 886615373357751*psi**2/(100000000000000*(1 + (-psi - 134335984549343*LambertW(-74440218185373*psi*exp(-74440218185373*psi/500000000000000)/500000000000000)/20000000000000)/psi)**3*(-74440218185373*psi/500000000000000 - LambertW(-74440218185373*psi*exp(-74440218185373*psi/500000000000000)/500000000000000))**2) + 600*psi/((1 + (-psi - 134335984549343*LambertW(-74440218185373*psi*exp(-74440218185373*psi/500000000000000)/500000000000000)/20000000000000)/psi)**4*(-psi - 134335984549343*LambertW(-74440218185373*psi*exp(-74440218185373*psi/500000000000000)/500000000000000)/20000000000000)))/(-74440218185373*psi**2*log(1 + (-psi - 134335984549343*LambertW(-74440218185373*psi*exp(-74440218185373*psi/500000000000000)/500000000000000)/20000000000000)/psi)/(50000000000000*(-74440218185373*psi/500000000000000 - LambertW(-74440218185373*psi*exp(-74440218185373*psi/500000000000000)/500000000000000))**2) + 134335984549343*psi/(2000000000000*(1 + (-psi - 134335984549343*LambertW(-74440218185373*psi*exp(-74440218185373*psi/500000000000000)/500000000000000)/20000000000000)/psi)*(-psi - 134335984549343*LambertW(-74440218185373*psi*exp(-74440218185373*psi/500000000000000)/500000000000000)/20000000000000))))/(-74440218185373*psi**2*log(1 + (-psi - 134335984549343*LambertW(-74440218185373*psi*exp(-74440218185373*psi/500000000000000)/500000000000000)/20000000000000)/psi)/(50000000000000*(-74440218185373*psi/500000000000000 - LambertW(-74440218185373*psi*exp(-74440218185373*psi/500000000000000)/500000000000000))**2) + 134335984549343*psi/(2000000000000*(1 + (-psi - 134335984549343*LambertW(-74440218185373*psi*exp(-74440218185373*psi/500000000000000)/500000000000000)/20000000000000)/psi)*(-psi - 134335984549343*LambertW(-74440218185373*psi*exp(-74440218185373*psi/500000000000000)/500000000000000)/20000000000000)))
```

I ran the code for one hour but still did not get an output. Is the integrand too complicated for `sympy` to integrate, or worse still, the resulting integral may not have a closed form solution?

Answer (score 1):

It's very unlikely to find a closed form for integrals as complicated as the one shown unless you can simplify them somehow.

Your expression has a repeating subexpression:

```
In [87]: d2crho_dpsi2.atoms(LambertW)
Out[87]: 
⎧ ⎛                   -74440218185373⋅ψ  ⎞⎫
⎪ ⎜                   ────────────────── ⎟⎪
⎪ ⎜                    500000000000000   ⎟⎪
⎨ ⎜-74440218185373⋅ψ⋅ℯ                   ⎟⎬
⎪W⎜──────────────────────────────────────⎟⎪
⎪ ⎝           500000000000000            ⎠⎪
⎩                                         ⎭
```

This is of the form `W(a*exp(a))` which is just equal to `a` for many values of `a` (it depends which branch of the W function you are on and the value of `a`). With that replacement the expression simplifies to zero:

```
In [88]: a = Wild('a')

In [89]: factor(d2crho_dpsi2).replace(LambertW(a*exp(a)), a)
Out[89]: 0
```

That replacement is only valid for

```
In [101]: solve(-74440218185373*psi/500000000000000 > -1).n()
Out[101]: ψ < 6.71679922746716
```

However beyond that point the same replacement would apply if you were thinking about the `W_{-1}` branch. Depending on which branch you intended it is possible that the correct answer here is just that your expression is equal to zero (hence easy to integrate).

See:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function#Inverse